# Export to Excel link I created not working in Chrome only (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel

So after a ton of research and trying to figure out how to make this work, I've finally gotten frustrated enough to post here. I have to create a button that can export a list in SharePoint 2010 to Excel (I know that there's a feature that does this, I'm trying to make it easier for people by just having this button displayed above the list).

**Here's what I have so far**:

```
https://PATH TO SITE/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List={LIST ID IS HERE}&View={VIEW ID IS HERE}&RowLimit=0&RootFolder=FOLDER PATH
```

Of course, I've filled in all of the capital parts with the information (but for privacy purposes have left them out of here). This link it basically attached to an image I made to make it a button.

**Here's the issue**: this works well on IE, but when trying it on Chrome is just opens up a new page and shows me this link on the page with a few other lines of stuff I don't understand. Anybody have any idea why it's not working on Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

This is the behavior, it doesn't work. You aren't doing anything wrong. If you are replicating what the ribbon button does, it will only work in IE. I'm fairly certain it is one of the few ActiveX objects remaining.

So in short, there isn't anything you can do, it is a Chrome limitation.